# python string slicing with alternating strides

Tags: python, string, slice

Is there an elegant way to perform python slicing with more than one stride?

For example, given an input string, create string which contains the characters in positions: 1,4,6,9,11,14,16,19 and so forth

Input example:

```
s = "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Output:

```
out = "behkmpruwz"
```

Comment: I don't think slicing with more than one stride is possible directly in the stdlib. If you don't have a stringent requirement to use slicing , then  options like a lambda in join, or zip etc are possible

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex solution which might meet your requirements:

```
s = "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
output = re.sub(r'.(.)..(.)', '\\1\\2', s)
print(s)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
behkmpruwz
```

The pattern matches five characters at a time, capturing the second and fifth characters in capture groups `\1` and `\2`.  Then, it just replaces those five characters with the two single captured characters.

This happens to work perfectly for your input string, because it is exactly a multiple of 5 in length.  Note that my pattern won't do any replacements to any characters 1 to 4 which exceed a multiple length of 5.

Comment: Can you explain a bit on this RE? Is it like every 2nd and 5th characters?

Comment: Thanks, btw, I liked the RE :-) . Not sure this is the answer  the owner is looking for :-

Comment: _"because it is exactly a multiple of 5 in length."_ - which IMO hints to a typo in the example string (lacking `g`), as this is not true for the alphabet... :)

Comment: @SpghttCd I mean, if the input does _not_ have to be a multiple of 5, then the OP should really tell us what happens in that case.  One possible interpretation is that a slice doesn't happen unless we have a 1-1 and 2-1 present together.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use external libraries, then one general solution is to calculate the correct index yourself and join the corresponding characters.

```
start1 = 0
start2 = 1
stride1 = 5
stride2 = 3

result = ''.join([s[i + j] for i in range(start1, len(s), stride1) 
                           for j in range(start2, stride1, stride2)])
```

If you do not mind using libraries such as `numpy`, then you can make the input into N-d arrays (in this case, a 2-D matrix) and apply advanced slicing on multiple axes.

```
import numpy as np

start1 = 0
start2 = 1
stride1 = 5
stride2 = 3
s_mat = np.array([*s]).reshape(stride1, -1)  # Reshape the input into a 5 by 5 matrix
result_mat = s_mat[start1:, start2::stride2].flatten()   # Apply slicing and flatten the result into a 1-D array
result = ''.join(result_mat)  # Merge the output array into a string
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the loops like this. Not sure if its the perfect fit.

```
stride_1_seq = s[1::3]
stride_2_seq = s[4::5]
extracted_str = "".join(map(lambda x,y: x+y, stride_1_seq, stride_2_seq))
```

This should work, if the intervals are configured well.